# Deleting all HTML elements inside of div

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="conditional-one">
     <div class="large-12 columns">
          <h3><?php echo $arrayStage_rule_one_title?></h3>
          <p>
             <?php echo $arrayStage_rule_one_description?>
          </p>
          <ul style="list-style-type:disc; margin-left:10px;">
             <?php echo $arrayStage_rule_one_description_bullets?>
          </ul>
          <h3><?php echo $arrayStage_rule_one_bullets_title?></h3>
          <br>
          <ul style="list-style-type:disc; margin-left:10px;">
             <?php echo $html_rule_one_bullets?>
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

And i'm trying to erase all the HTML elements inside of the div with `id="conditional-one"` if this conditional is met:

```
// select div by ID
var conditionalOne = document.getElementById("conditional-one");

// Assign PHP strings to JavaScript variables
var conditionalOneText = '<?php echo $place_bullet_one?>';

if (conditionalOneText !== "1" || conditionalOneText !== "2") {
     conditionalOne.removeChild(conditionalOne.firstChild);
} else {
     // do nothing
}
```

Currently ConditionalOneText is == 3 but the divs inside the `conditional-one` aren't being erased. Can anybody help me erase all of the HTML elements inside of the `conditional-one` div if the condition is met?

Comment: What is being erased, if anything?

Comment: if you want to use removeChild you have to loop through your firstchild nodes like that: while (conditionalOne.firstChild) {
                conditionalOne.removeChild(conditionalOne.firstChild);
            }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove all the contents by setting **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** to `""`.

Also, if you really aren't going to do anything in your `else` block, then you can just remove it altogether, which will eliminate potential confusion in your code.

```
// select div by ID
var conditionalOne = document.getElementById("conditional-one");

// Assign PHP strings to JavaScript variables
var conditionalOneText = '<?php echo $place_bullet_one?>';

if (conditionalOneText !== "1" || conditionalOneText !== "2") {
     // You can remove all nested HTML content simply by setting
     // the innerHTML property of the element to "".
     conditionalOne.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: I was going to post this exact answer word for word.

Comment: Nice. I'd love to know why OP's version didn't work.

Comment: Right. OP should have specified what does happen.

Comment: @DaniSpringer The OP's example fails because `firstChild` in this case is a text node of white space, not the div element

Comment: @DaniSpringer EVERYTHING in the DOM is a node, but not all nodes are element nodes. The carriage returns in your code are text nodes. If the OPs code was: `conditionalOne.removeChild(conditionalOne.firstChild.nextElementSibling);` it would have worked as this property finds siblings that are elements.

Comment: Hi @scott thanks for the solution and suggestions about erasing the `else` block. Sorry for not mentioning why it wasn't working @Dani. The elements weren't being deleted.

Comment: @marcos You're welcome. Don't forget to mark as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some jQuery

```
$('.divClass1 div').empty();    // clears
$('.dicClass2 div').remove();   // deletes
```